# Use sed to append a file into another file

Tags: text-processing, sed

I've been trying to append `file.bak` into `file.php` using this command:

```
sed r file.php file.bak
```

It gives correct output as desired. However, it doesn't save that appended `file.bak` into `file.php`.

Any idea how to get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `sed` for this. It's enough to use `cat`:

```
cat file.bak >>file.php
```

This will append the contents of `file.bak` to the very end of `file.php`.

---

The `sed` program `r file.php` will output the contents of `file.php` to standard output *for each line of input*.  If `file.bak` has multiple lines, you will get multiple copies of `file.php` inserted.

This is not what you want if you want to use `sed` to append the data.

Instead, **ignoring the fact that `cat` does a better job here**,

```
sed '$r file.bak' file.php
```

This will not read `file.bak` until reaching the very last line of `file.php`.  This has the effect of concatenating the contents of the two files (the contents of `file.php` will come first, followed by the contents of `file.bak`).

To write the result back to `file.php` you may either redirect the output to a new file and then move that into place (the safe way):

```
sed '$r file.bak' file.php >tmpfile && mv tmpfile file.php
```

or, you may use the `-i` option that some implementations of `sed` has (the unsafe way):

```
sed -i '$r file.bak' file.php
```

Comment: I used cat option but it's appending at the top of file, how can it be appended at the bottom?

Comment: @CryptoMiningPoolSetupYiimp I might well have misunderstood what file you wanted to add to the end.  `cat file1 >>file2` will add the contents of `file1` to the end of `file2`.  Modify this command to fit your particular situation.

Comment: @CryptoMiningPoolSetupYiimp I interpreted "append `file.bak` into `file.php`" as "append `file.bak` to the end of `file.php`"...